# How to access non-existing property correctly in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror

I am trying to write this piece of code where a boolean value is extracted from an array of objects with a default value if the property does not exists

```typescript
const flagArrayToBooleanArray_INITIAL_ERROR = (
  arr: Array<{ value: string } | { value: string; flag: true }> = [{
    value: "",
  }, { value: "", flag: true }],
) => {
  const flags: Array<boolean> = arr.map((obj) => obj.flag ?? false);
  return flags;
};

}
```

Typescript complains on the function `({ flag }) => flag ?? false` as property `flag` does not exist on type `Empty  | { flag: true }`

This can be fixed by converting te object to a map

```typescript
function flagArrayToBooleanArrayFixedMap(
  arr: Array<{ value: string } | { value: string; flag: true }> = [{ value: "" }, { value: "", flag: true }],
) {
  return arr.map((obj) => {
    const tmp = new Map(Object.entries(obj));

    return tmp.get("flag") === true ? true : false;
  });
}
```

Is there a way to tell typescript `I know this might not exist, I want the default js behaviour in this case`?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgGYBsCGBzAggJx2gTwBUIAhCCFAUzSl3wIH0BlAeQBkBVIgSVYDkEAXgQAKUAgRo8ALgT1CAHgDeCAG5oUAVypz4OAJZQMCAL4IAPglUbtuhPqMYA3MnQY5cHDrMA%20YQgA2jaaOnIAROFmADTW6qH2kbGomJ7eVGYAutGgAJTC-soSCJCwiCkYMHIKBIoARhTUtP4i0jgAdAC2aAAOoqIQdQBW%20UK%20xZKi4RVRRgiDIwgAZEtirMNUYHDtPTgQcPsEPVTtABZoMKwA7lAACnvHOHAE7XVGACYDw7lTM7m5E0kCAA-PNhu0KoDJHIkJoYFRirlnMUcFQ4FocFA3JgYMiQKY8aBSvBsdg8IQSORKDQ6OSmDx%20DxeFh2IwAKIAJQ5rA5AXEIEkbWqdJU8Tsei8TjMljitjCDklxlcFTSPlMLSCRQFQLliXCOW1pliIXFCCSpNVGVM2TyBWsxWJ5XcVXkIoa1OaATaXV6-QWo38Cwh7hBoNhKHhSJRaIxWIquNABNAyZASC0UC2BmgpJqlMaNJqADEDAAPKjvACyvuKQtdDFFuolhmM0qsJvljiVFoQXjVGuCYvlkRisoSEX13d7VptIHyWskqPRmKkeB9fS%20izG9u1kkdPc6PQCUCoVwQVb66yGm22VCgkqoMA3-0JO4Qi9j%20567QwaN%207nCoxCCIU4gj26QIDCcJUHikimFG%20JAA)

Edit: Fixed some copy-paste errors, in the initial code there was no compiler error.

Comment: What version of TypeScript, and what flags are you using? On the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmUUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGikogDcJcA+AbgCguAzAV0qZg5bJSi8ANgENqAQVy5pIACrYAQtmySI0ygqUgAFFyhRpigFxQDywvEQgoAHygBvCTOrWy-aAF82FCgAbTd-eg8pWR9cPyh-AF1aLgBKd1MoHEpST1lia1sQQgAjLR09INQLXAA6OGkwIyMorwT05CDo6igAfl6JaUliCFTuM1wIYH5ccW7ibn8gA) with the latest version and default options, I don't get any errors with your original code (which surprises me somewhat). Can you share a playground example replicating the error?

Comment: Also, wouldn't `Array<{ flag?: true }>` be suitable, rather than `Array<Empty | {flag: true}>`? My TypeScript is still only so-so, there may well be a subtlety there I'm missing.

Comment: The problem with your current code is that it thinks the `.map` would return `true[]` and you have to tell it otherwise. [This works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmUUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGikogDcJcA+AbgFgAoXgMwCulTMHLZKUfgBsAhtQCCuXLJAAVbACFs2aRFmUlKkAApeUKLOUAuKEdWF4iEFAA+UAN5S51W2UHQAL5sKFAA2h6B9F4y8n64AVCBALq0vACUnuZQOJSk3vLEoVa4AHRwsmAmAB4oISYA5LHUDVBUUNWZAPwdpc1Qtvyy0sQQ6dw8FrgQwIK4ks3EE4G8vLn5TMMBxLb2II4ISO4xPvGJwaERUZ7XJ3FQ-hC3KRPrwFDTxILS76jNexptLp9IZlKoTJtpNtxmsJMRgaVpNhqCZPt9gDCeEA) by testing `'flag' in x` for `.map` over `x`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It *works*, but if you take off the hard typing from `const flags: Array<boolean>`, the compiler thinks `flags` is a `true[]`. So works but funky (If there is a `flag` property, it must be true, so the result of the map is `true[]`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you hover over the `.map`. specifically or remove the type from `flags`, you can see that it is `true[]`. Since the `.map` iterates over `{ flag }` specifically, and the items that have `flag` properties are all `true`, then the `?? false` would not ever come into play, *unless you are lying to the compiler*.

Comment: @crashmstr - See? I was being dense. :-D You said, right there in your earlier comment. That doesn't seem to be what the OP's asking about, but it does need fixing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for the suggestion, I will try to be more present in the future,

Comment: In the end I went for this solution with the `in` operator, 

(playground)[https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKABGDGD2B2DOAXMAzANgQwOYEEBOeGAngCrQBC00aAphrPoUWALxgAUoEEGBAXGEbEAPAG8wANwxoArjQFI8AS1hYwAXzAAfMOKmz5YRSqwBuVJiwDEeORoB8rMAG1RXbhH1yBAIh8Aadwh1f11JaW8wP1D0bGtbGg0AXUDwMABKVkc3NIgYBGRYrHgBISJhACMqWnpHNl48ADoAWwwAB3Z2aAqAK0yWeyDudh8inzAVMG6+sAAyWY4AeV6aSERGtrxoRG2iNppGgAsMeEWAd1gABS39vEQiRoqVABMu3vSRsfT0oY8AfimvUaRV+3AEKGk8BoQ3SpiGeBoiBkeFgFmw8DhaXUpiAA]

Which is not to elegant, but I wanted to avoid changing the input type

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, The example provided does not cause errors indeed; It was a mistake on my part, I wanted to simplify the type `{value:string;flag:true;}` by removing the value field that does not get used in the example, but I realized that `{}` is not the type of the empty object and apparently the `never` in `Record<string, never>` has some semantic i do not understand yet.

 Here is an example of the original error message:

(continue in next comment)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgGYBsCGBzAggJx2gTwBUIAhCCFAUzSl3wIQF4EAKUBBNPALgXsIAeAN4IAbmhQBXKn3g4AllAwIAvggA+CUROmyE8pRgDcydBj5wcMtQD5mCANrCOncZJl8ARF4A0r1V9tdz1vPzNMS2sqNQBdfxAASmZ7FxBOSFhEVEwYPgECQQAjCmpaexZuHAA6AFs0AAdWVggigCtkpltXTlYvHIwvBCUEVo6EADIJtgB5dqowOGqGnAg4NYIGqmqACzQYGYB3KAAFVa2cOAJqoqUAExb2xL6Br0TEnrcAflH26oHPpw+EhJDAqK5EsZXDgqHApDgoBEMDAoSBVKjQJl4EiCiRyJQaHQ8IQAPoAdQASjMAHIAcQc7HSXF4-GJhR0Hn0hmUak0wV0ngMViMpgGURsqgqTjSbhCgp8CU4gX5nLCQTFCCsEvioE6qVcWOy5jyrIYxVKhKlVTqjWaYz1vza-3MCC+PxBKDBkOhsPhiIGKNA6KAA

Comment: @afiori - Thanks. You can edit the question to correct or expand it. (When doing so, it's important to be careful not to invalidate or incorporate existing answers, though.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have items that may or may not have flags, having that typed correctly higher up would make this easier.

You can also define a type that may or may not have a flag property. Any object can "meet" that criteria (but may be `undefined`).

```
type MayHaveFlag = { flag?: boolean };

function flagArrayToBooleanArray(
  arr: MayHaveFlag[]
) {
  const flags = arr.map(({ flag }) => !!flag);
  return flags;
}

const values = [{}, {}, { flag: true }, { dont: 'care', what: 'this', has: 1 }];
const result = flagArrayToBooleanArray(values);
console.log(result);
```

So here, when we `.map` over the objects, we get `true`, `false`, or `undefined` as any of those could be values from any object. We can then use `!!` to force into a `true` or `false` (`undefined` becomes `false`, other values stay the same) or you could keep `flag ?? false` if you prefer, as that would do the same thing.

You can note that my `values` array does not even need a type declared, as the function parameter really has no requirements of the object other than that if it has a `flag` property, it is `boolean`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmUUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGikogDcJcA+AbgFgAoXgMwCulTMHLZKUfgBsAhtQCCuXLJAAVbACFs2aRFmUlKkAApeUKLOUAuKEdWF4iEFAA+UAN5S51W2UHQAL5sKFAA2h6B9F4y8n64AVCBALq0vACUnuZQOJSk3vLEtvYghABGOnoGIahWuAB0cLJgJiYxPkmZyCGx1FAA-P1SstLEEOncPBa4EMCCuJK9xJOBQA)

Comment: Thanks, This looks like the correct idiomatic way to do this; In this case I did not want to change the signature of the function so I chose to check for ` ("flag" in obj)` in the map to make the compiler happy.